# Eclipse And Linux: Keyboard unusable after gnome-screen-saver

Tags: linux, keyboard, eclipse

I know this is not programming related. But I can't find any topics on Google or UbuntuForums.

So the problem is:
When gnome-screensaver starts on the moment Eclipse has the focus and I wake up again my laptop, Eclipse doesn't listen to keyboard-events. To solve this I have to change the focus to another program and then back to Eclipse. Than it works again.

This isn't a real problem, but it would be nice if someone can solve it.

Thanks

Comment: If your issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/450021, please help add more information to that bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is at all related, but are you setting the GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS environment variable as described in [question 1816485](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816485/eclipse-galileo-click-problem-on-ubuntu-9-10)?  This solved eclipse button click/focus problems for me under Ubuntu.